# Find player name who scored max number of goals?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to find the name of maximum goal scorer and goals scored.

`GOAL_DETAILS(GOAL_ID,PLAYER_ID,TEAM_ID,GOAL_TIME)`

`PLAYER_MAST(PLAYER_ID,PLAYER_NAME)`

I have done this using `join` but unable to do it with subquery.
Please help.

1st Approach:

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID,
       PLAYER_NAME
FROM   PLAYER_MAST 
WHERE  PLAYER_ID IN ( SELECT PLAYER_ID,
                             COUNT(PLAYER_ID) 
                      FROM   GOAL_DETAILS
                      GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
                      HAVING COUNT(PLAYER_ID)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
                                               FROM GOAL_DETAILS
                                               GROUP BY PLAYER_ID)
                    );
```

2nd Approach:

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID,
       PLAYER_NAME
FROM   PLAYER_MAST 
WHERE  PLAYER_ID IN (SELECT PLAYER_ID,
                            COUNT(PLAYER_ID) 
                     FROM   GOAL_DETAILS
                     GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
                     HAVING COUNT(PLAYER_ID)=MAX(COUNT(PLAYER_ID))
                    );
```

3rd Approach:

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID,
       PLAYER_NAME
FROM   PLAYER_MAST 
WHERE  PLAYER_ID IN (SELECT PLAYER_ID,
                            MAX(COUNT(*))
                     FROM   GOAL_DETAILS
                     GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
                    ) ;
```

I know these will print the names only not total goals scored but they are not even printing names.

Where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.PLAYER_ID, p.PLAYER_NAME, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM PLAYER_MAST p
    INNER JOIN GOAL_DETAILS g
        ON p.PLAYER_ID = g.PLAYER_ID
    GROUP BY p.PLAYER_ID, p.PLAYER_NAME
)

SELECT PLAYER_ID, PLAYER_NAME
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you instead might want to capture all players tied for first place, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`.  Note that I aggregated both by `PLAYER_ID` and `PLAYER_NAME`, in case two players might happen to have the same name.

Comment: after 1 hour i have my sql exam if you can tell me the errors in above program it will be really helpful
that why it is not printing the name of highest goal  scorer?
I know your method is best but now time is less please help brother

Comment: @akashking honestly the version I gave above is what I would recommend using here.  Do you expect to be asked to write the query some other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
with goal_details(goal_id,player_id,team_id,goal_time) as (
select 1, 1, 1, 10 from dual union all
select 2, 2, 2, 20 from dual union all
select 3, 2, 2, 30 from dual union all
select 3, 3, 3, 30 from dual
),
player_mast(player_id,player_name) as (
select 1, 'First'  from dual union all
select 2, 'Second' from dual union all
select 3, 'Thirth' from dual
)
select
max(p.player_id)   keep (dense_rank last order by count(*))              as max_scorer_id,
max(p.player_name) keep (dense_rank last order by count(*), p.player_id) as max_scorer_mame,
max(count(*))                                                            as max_count
from goal_details d
join player_mast  p on p.player_id = d.player_id
group by p.player_id, p.player_name;

MAX_SCORER_ID MAX_SC  MAX_COUNT
------------- ------ ----------
            2 Second          2
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where I am doing it wrong?

You get an `ORA-00913: too many values` exception

This is because you have the syntax:

```
WHERE value1 IN ( SELECT value1, value2 ....
```

and your `IN` filter must have the same number of values on the left as are in the list to the right; so remove the `COUNT(PLAYER_ID)` part of your sub-query's return values:

```
WHERE PLAYER_ID IN ( SELECT PLAYER_ID FROM ....
```

Then your first attempt should work:

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID,
       PLAYER_NAME
FROM   PLAYER_MAST 
WHERE  PLAYER_ID IN ( SELECT PLAYER_ID
                      FROM   GOAL_DETAILS
                      GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
                      HAVING COUNT(PLAYER_ID)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
                                               FROM GOAL_DETAILS
                                               GROUP BY PLAYER_ID)
                    );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3919c6b7b180f6bb86cc213be6cc31b5)